# How to Suppress JIT optimization in .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, .net-core, coreclr, dnspy

I can't find a way to suppress JIT optimization in a .NET Core 2.2 process. This prevents me from attaching with a debugger in production and seeing all local variables.

In .NET Framework I could add an INI file with the same name as the DLL I wanted to prevent optimization as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/making-an-image-easier-to-debug). But this doesn't seem to work with .NET Core.

Debuggers like Visual Studio and dnSpy are able to suppress optimization when starting a process so it must be possible somehow. As a workaround, I could have started a process with a debugger but I'm using IIS and can't find a way to start the w3wp worker with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting environment variable `COMPlus_JITMinOpts=1` for the process

Comment: Have you tried (if at all possible) to deploy debug build to production? It must be some environment variable... You could start process with a debugger where you notice JIT optimization is suppressed, and then make the application to output all its environment variables.

Comment: Also make sure that your app actually sees `COMPlus_JITMinOpts=1` by making the app to output that value to console or somewhere else.

Comment: @AlexBuyny Yes I made sure with logging :) As for deploying debug build - yes, it works but that's exactly what I want to avoid. I want to be able to change without redeploying.